# soap wsdl connection refused error (111)

Tags: wsdl, connection, nusoap, sugarcrm

I got this error upon trying to connect nusoap api for sugarcrm 6.4.3

```
wsdl error: Getting http://url:8080/soap.php?wsdl - HTTP ERROR: 
Couldn't open socket, connection to server http://url:8080/soap.php?wsdl, Error (111): Connection refused
```

so is there settings I need to do to open the socket for successful connection ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Make sure your server is up and running.
2. Make sure you're trying to connect to correct address and port.

Comment: @Secator ok thanks...I have asked clients to inquire about these with their hosting provider.